# Speed up using multi threading python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, python-multithreading

Actually I am creating a proxy checker but the problem is it is taking a lot of time to check because there are a lot of the proxies

```
def proxy():
    lives = []
    allproxy = []

    def fetch_proxy():
        raw_proxy = []
        res = requests.get(proxy_api)
        raw_proxy = res.text.splitlines()
        return raw_proxy

    allproxy = fetch_proxy()

    for proxy in allproxy:
        try:

            proxyDictChk = { 
                          "https"  : "https://"+proxy, 
                          "http" : "http://"+proxy,
                        }
            res = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies=proxyDictChk,timeout=3)
            print("Proxy is Working")
            lives.append(proxy)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Proxy Dead")
    return lives

print(proxy())
```

I am curious that how I can use multithreading here to make this fast

PS. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you make a local function fetch_proxy? Which part takes a long time the for proxy loop?

Answer (score 0):

The python docs provide a pretty good example, https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

```
# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(check_proxy, url, 60): url for url in allproxy}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            is_valid = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%s page is %s' % (url, is_valid))
```

So you would just need to define the function check_proxy.

```
def check_proxy( proxy ):
    try:
        proxyDictChk = { 
                      "https"  : "https://"+proxy, 
                      "http" : "http://"+proxy,
                    }
        res = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies=proxyDictChk,timeout=3)
        print("Proxy is Working")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Proxies Dead!")
        return False
```

Essentially, use an executor and submit a function that does what you want. Then use the future to get the results of the functions as they're completed.

Also, since this lets the exception bubble up, you don't have to handle it in the function.

```
def check_proxy( proxy ):
    proxyDictChk = { "https"  : "https://"+proxy, 
                      "http" : "http://"+proxy,
                    }
    res = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies=proxyDictChk,timeout=3)
    return True
```

Now the exception can be handled at the future state. You could change the return type to something more meaningful.